# Scrapy: No module named items, scraping images

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying a example that use scrapy to download images form a web pages.

This is the spider file:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Item, Field, Request
from items import TrousersItem
class TrouserScraper(Spider):
    name, start_urls = "Trousers_spider", ["http://lookatmyfuckingredtrousers.blogspot.co.uk"]
    def parse(self, response):
        for image in response.selector.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "entry-content")]/div[contains(@class, "separator")]/a/img/@src'):
             yield TrousersItem(image_urls=[image.extract()])
        for url in response.selector.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'blog-pager-older-link')]/@href"):
            yield Request(url.extract(), callback=self.parse)
```

And the items.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item


class TrousersItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

When I type

```
scrapy crawl Trousers_spider
```

I get this error:

> No module named items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [import `items` from your project package](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#using-our-item):

```
from yourproject.items import TrousersItem
```

Assuming [regular Scrapy project structure](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project).