# How to fix 'No module found' and 'int object has no attribute 'splitlines'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, scrapy

I'm trying to run a spider on my website and running a scrapyrt listen server on my desktop.  It tells me my module 'webscrape' cannot be found when I run the spider and also gives me an 'Int object has no splitlines attribute.'

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/311 provides a solution for scrapyd.
https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyrt/pull/84 appears to still be an issue.

So, I'm really at a loss here.

error code:

```
2019-08-12 16:37:47-0700 [scrapyrt] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 2196, in allContentReceived
            req.requestReceived(command, path, version)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 920, in requestReceived
            self.process()
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py", line 199, in process
            self.render(resrc)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py", line 259, in render
            body = resrc.render(self)
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\resources.py", line 26, in render
            result = resource.Resource.render(self, request)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\resource.py", line 250, in render
            return m(request)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\resources.py", line 127, in render_GET
            return self.prepare_crawl(api_params, scrapy_request_args, **kwargs)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\resources.py", line 217, in prepare_crawl
            start_requests=start_requests, *args, **kwargs)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\resources.py", line 226, in run_crawl
            dfd = manager.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\core.py", line 157, in crawl
            self.get_project_settings(), self)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\core.py", line 178, in get_project_settings
            return get_project_settings(custom_settings=custom_settings)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\conf\spider_settings.py", line 27, in get_project_settings
            crawler_settings.setmodule(module, priority='project')
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 288, in setmodule
            module = import_module(module)
          File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked

          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked

        builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webscrape'

Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 2196, in allContentReceived
    req.requestReceived(command, path, version)
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 920, in requestReceived
    self.process()
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py", line 199, in process
    self.render(resrc)
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py", line 259, in render
    body = resrc.render(self)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\resources.py", line 26, in render
    result = resource.Resource.render(self, request)
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\resource.py", line 250, in render
    return m(request)
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\resources.py", line 127, in render_GET
    return self.prepare_crawl(api_params, scrapy_request_args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\resources.py", line 217, in prepare_crawl
    start_requests=start_requests, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\resources.py", line 226, in run_crawl
    dfd = manager.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\core.py", line 157, in crawl
    self.get_project_settings(), self)
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\core.py", line 178, in get_project_settings
    return get_project_settings(custom_settings=custom_settings)
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\conf\spider_settings.py", line 27, in get_project_settings
    crawler_settings.setmodule(module, priority='project')
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 288, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked

builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webscrape'

2019-08-12 16:37:47-0700 [-] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\protocols\basic.py", line 572, in dataReceived
            why = self.lineReceived(line)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 2105, in lineReceived
            self.allContentReceived()
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 2196, in allContentReceived
            req.requestReceived(command, path, version)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 920, in requestReceived
            self.process()
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py", line 199, in process
            self.render(resrc)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py", line 259, in render
            body = resrc.render(self)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\resources.py", line 31, in render
            return self.render_object(result, request)
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\resources.py", line 95, in render_object
            request.setHeader('Content-Length', len(r))
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 1271, in setHeader
            self.responseHeaders.setRawHeaders(name, [value])
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http_headers.py", line 220, in setRawHeaders
            for v in self._encodeValues(values)]
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http_headers.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
            for v in self._encodeValues(values)]
          File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http_headers.py", line 40, in _sanitizeLinearWhitespace
            return b' '.join(headerComponent.splitlines())
        builtins.AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines'


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py", line 199, in process
    self.render(resrc)
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py", line 259, in render
    body = resrc.render(self)
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\resources.py", line 31, in render
    return self.render_object(result, request)
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\resources.py", line 95, in render_object
    request.setHeader('Content-Length', len(r))
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 1271, in setHeader
    self.responseHeaders.setRawHeaders(name, [value])
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http_headers.py", line 220, in setRawHeaders
    for v in self._encodeValues(values)]
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http_headers.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    for v in self._encodeValues(values)]
  File "c:\users\user\microblog\job-visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http_headers.py", line 40, in _sanitizeLinearWhitespace
    return b' '.join(headerComponent.splitlines())
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

Project Layout:

```
-Job-Visualizer

 -app

  -webscrape(scrapyrt ran from here in venv)

   -spiders
```

When running the spider the spider code should return the results as expected.

Edit:
Spider Code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class IndeedSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'indeedspider'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.indeed.com']

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Spider being ran...')
        self.start_url = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=financial+aid+advisor&l=Highland%2C+CA'
        self.links = []


    def modify_realtime_request(self, request):
        return SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args=splash_args, endpoint='render.html')

    def start_requests(self):
        print(self.start_url)
        urls = [
            self.start_url
        ]
        splash_args = {
            'html': 1,
            'png': 1,
            'width': 800,
            'render_all': 1,
        }
        for url in urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, endpoint='render.json', args=splash_args)

    def parse(self, response):
        html = response.body
        title = response.css('title').extract()
        titles = response.xpath("//div[@class= 'title']/a/text()").getall()
        locations = response.xpath("//div[@class= 'sjcl']/span/text()").getall()
        companies = response.css("div.sjcl.span.company a::text").getall()
        summarys = response.xpath("//div[@class= 'summary']/text()").getall()
```

Route Portion Code:

```
 params = {
                'spider_name': 'indeed_scraper',
                'start_requests': True
            }
            response = requests.get('http://localhost:9080/crawl.json', params)
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            print(data)
```

Comment: The error about `webscrape` indicates to me that the module/library is not available in your current environment. Are you sure you've activated your venv? Check your path? Can you import that module from a REPL?

Comment: The module webscrape is just a folder that contains the scrapy project directory.  Scrapyrt is being ran in (venv) /job-visualizer/app/webscrape.

Comment: OK, the `webscrape` error happens when you run scrapyrt? What are the imports you have in that script?

Comment: When I run scrapyrt it opens up a listen server which is good.  When I run my spider to crawl I get this:

Printing data scraped from spider
```
{'status': 'error', 'message': "No module named 'webscrape'", 'code': 500}
```
and the same No Module 'webscrape' error above in the main-post on scrapyrt.  The  'webscrape' module that is referenced in the scrapy project directory is in the settings where things are webscrape.spiders and scrapy.cfg where its webscrapy.settings and project = webscrape and a relative import in my crawl function(which doesn't even run using this method.)

Comment: Ah, perhaps try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804222/scrapy-no-module-named-items-scraping-images

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
When creating a scrapy project, make sure that scrapy.cfg is outside the SCRAPY project folder.

**Incorrect:**

```
-app
 - webscrape
  - scrapy.cfg
  - __init__.py
  - items.py
  - middleware.py
   - spiders
    - spider.py
```

**Correct:**

```
-app
- scrapy.cfg
 - webscrape
  - __init__.py
  - items.py
  - middleware.py
   - spiders
    - spider.py
```

**Correct Result:**

```
{"status": "ok", "items": [], "spider_name": "indeedspider"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the module webscrape? Also you are using the wrong type of object so there is no splitlines attribute. If you print the object type, does it show as an int?
Splitlines method only works on a string so you need to make sure the object you are calling it with is a string and not an int datatype.

Comment: I was importing a custom items class to handle the data being scraped but I commented the code and imports for that.  I've edited the above to include the spider code and my route function for handling the crawl.

Comment: OK there are two separate issues here. Using a string datatype should solve one of the problems.

Comment: Okay so what should I be doing differently?  I've seen people doing str(spider) but my spider information is already in str format.

Comment: More specifically the headerComponent needs to be a string.

Comment: Okay well I solved the issue by using this comment as a guide: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/311#issuecomment-494660965

I'm still getting 'no module named webscrape' when running though